# send data from jQuery to laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm using laravel and i want to receive data from jQuery to my controller to insert it to the database , i tried many methodes but without success 
this is my script :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
});
$.ajax({
   url:'/test',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {
      "name": "Name",
      "color": "red",
    },
});
```

and the controller :

```
public function test()
{
  if(Request::ajax()) {
      $data = Input::all();
  }
  dd(json_decode($data));  
}
```

and finally the Route :

```
Route::post('/test',[
    'uses' => 'TagsController@test'
]);
```

it seems ok for me but the result :( :
[image]

Comment: Route::post('test', 'TagsController@test'); php artisan route:list in command line to check if the route registered. Clear the route cache and config if it did not

Comment: also $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php", you need to use method not type. Check the manual

Comment: @Indra You can use `type` or `method`. While `type` is deprecated, it has not been removed, nor does it have a removal estimate.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I know, but it's better to not have to update your code every time you update a library. Also better for the poor souls who come after you. I always recommend doing as the manual says.

Comment: i removed the type and i cheked the route but the same problem

Comment: Did you check that full route or path in the network inspector ?

Comment: yes i did many times i think that because i'm using laravel 5.6 no ?

Comment: show what the 404 not found give what error stack?

Comment: you have this in head, right?  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> do you see the route when you do php artisan route:list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in your controller, because you don't tell the server, which table do you want to use to store your data
or maybe because of your url.. jquery does not understand what is `{{}}`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    method: 'post',
    data: $('#form-id').serialize(), // prefer use serialize method
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);          
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function test(Request $request)
{
  if($request::ajax()) {
      $data = $request->color;
  }
  dd(json_decode($data));  
}
```

I am using serialize because It's so powerful, I don't need to input one by one the field name

I don't know if your controller is used for only retrieve the data from client or you want to use ajax to store your data in database.. so, I am using `$request->color` to make sure that the data is retrieved from the client side

Comment: i tried this but it tells me : Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically

Comment: thanks , it works but with juste when i changed use Illuminate/http/request by use Request directly

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in main blade page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And instead of old scholl jquery ajax.. just use Axios. it exist inside app.js. simple and very easy. it already detect the csrd-token meta tag. so no need to do in the form or header

change this

```
$.ajax({

    url: '{{route("test")}}',
    method: 'post',
    data : {
       "name": "Name",
       "color": "red",
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);          
    }

});
```

to this

```
axios.post('{{route("test")}}', {
    "name": "Name",
    "color": "red"
})
.then(function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
});
```

Your Route must be like this.

```
Route::post('/test',[
    'uses' => 'TagsController@test'
])->name('test');
```

Your controller seems fine..

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
   if($request->wantsJson()) {
      $data = $request::all();
      return $data;
   }
}
```

Comment: i also tried it but it says : Method wantJson does not exist.